# Skim Inverse Search Problem with Sublime Text 2

Tags: forward-inverse-search, sublime-text

Skim Inverse Search doesn't work for me(Mac OS 10.9)

Everything works fine for Sublime Text 2 with LaTexTools, building etc. Skim pops out, fine. Test PDF looks good. I set up sync in Skim wish to have inverse search, unfortunately, doesn't work.

Please note: I have also set up Sublime Text 2, LaTexTools, Sumatra PDF viewer in windows before as well. Everything works perfect. I double-click on a line in pdf and sublime text navigates to my desired location. So does the inverse search in Skim works in the same gesture manner as Sumatra does? Or I need extra configuration in Mac OS?

Thanks in advance!

My version of app:(all application installed in default location and settings)

Mac os 10.9

Sublime Text 2.02

LaTexTools release 2014-3-12

Skim 1.4.8(82)

My Skim sync setup in the picture:
[image: Sync setup]

Comment: Mine is fine(OSx 10.8.5). I am using latexmk and Cmd+shift+click work fine. I have this `$pdflatex = 'xelatex -recorder --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error -synctex=1'` in my .latexmkrc . It might not be important.

Comment: Yes Cmd+shift+click works for me as well! Thanks! But here is another problem: how did you know that? I've searched for all documentation but I can not find such information. I think it will be nice for you to post the source (if exists) in case people like me who is interested to look into it. :D Thanks @Aung

Comment: okay I will post the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mine is fine(OSx 10.8.5). I am using latexmk and Cmd+shift+click work fine. I have this $pdflatex = 'xelatex -recorder --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error -synctex=1' in my .latexmkrc . It might not be important.

For more information , please take a look [here](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools#forward-and-inverse-search) under the section **Forward and Inverse Search**.

Comment: To make it work I needed to go in the `Skim` preferences (`cmd+,`), in the Sync section, and select sublime text in the `preset` dropdown (instructions found [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/skim-app/wiki/TeX_and_PDF_Synchronization/#activating-backward-search-from-skim))